# Nav Drawer Menu alternative for the thumb zone

Tags: mobile, thumb

I'm currently playing with/exploring ideas for a mobile email UI, that:

1. Has as less UI elements as possible, while keeping it simple and usable
2. Most or all UI elements must be in the thumb zone for easy access/ergonomics

Here's [my Framer-prototype](https://framer.cloud/NJfFq) ('fan art' for the ProtonMail app).

I think the auto-hiding menu thingie is an interesting solution. But the standard Android Nav Drawer has the limitation that some important menu items remain at the top left part of the screen (hard to reach).

Are there any suitable alternatives to the nav drawer that are 'thumb-zone-friendly'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Modal bottom sheets](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-modal-bottom-sheets) which, according to Google:

> Modal bottom sheets are alternatives to menus, or simple dialogs (...)

and helps you solve the problem you have:

> (...) that some important menu items remain at the top left part of the screen (hard to reach).

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure if a bottom sheet would be optimal since I have a lot of items in my menu, but I'll definitely explore the possibility!